# Quadratic Reciprocity Joke

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, soft-question

I found a joke on a site made by user Zev Chonoles on quadratic reciprocity, the joke is as follows:

$$\text{Quadratic reciprocity: } \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right), \text{ up to sign.}$$

I assume it's a joke because the quadratic characters on opposite sides of the equality can only take on values $\pm 1$ (assuming $p \ne q$ are distinct primes) making the statement trivial.

That is the joke right? If not can someone explain

Comment: Indeed, the sign is the crucial information here, so "up to sign" is a joke. Like "Every number is prime, up to integers".

Comment: [Yep](http://i.imgur.com/iBZlG2A.jpg).

Comment: Hmmm...@DietrichBurde , what'd "up to integers" mean within this context? I don't get it...

Comment: @DonAntonio “Up to integer multiples”

Comment: @egreg, that didn't help. What would "$\;12$\; is a prime up to integer (multiples)" mean? That $\;12\;$ is just like $\;3\;$ since $\;12=3\cdot 4\;$ ? That's strange...

Comment: @DonAntonio You seem not to be good at jokes. `;-)`

Comment: To non-funny ones, @egreg ...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the joke, but a related fact is that systematizing and simplifying the sign (such as eliminating it, or making it independent of $p$ and $q$) was part of the motivation for using other forms of the symbol instead of Legendre's.  For example, $(p,q)=(q,p)$ for the Hilbert symbol.